# What are the computer-like objects in the Emperor's throne room?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, death-star

In *Return of the Jedi*, the Emperor's throne room contains these clusters of what appear to computer panels. What is the purpose of these? How can they be accessed?

[image: computer panels or terminals or something]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

These are described as "Duty Posts" in the [Star Wars: Inside the Worlds - Complete Locations](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Complete_Locations_(2016)) factbook. Apparently they lift up to allow access from underneath.

[image]

The Wookieepedia article on [Command Sector Duty Posts](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Command_sector_duty_posts) contains a wealth of detail about their operation, all copied almost verbatim from the [Haynes Death Star Manual](https://haynes.com/en-gb/imperial-death-star-manual) (which itself seems to have been cribbed from the earlier [Death Star Technical Manual](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Star_Technical_Companion), created as a supplement to the [Star Wars: RPG](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Roleplaying_Game))

> On the Death Stars, those who man the stations have a rank of
>   lieutenant or higher, and two to four can be stationed at any time.
>   These served as a "mini bridge" for the commanding officer(s) in
>   question. They were extendible at the base to allow access to the
>   assigned commanding officer(s).
>
> The duty posts were surrounded by eight control boards, four of which
>   were dedicated to the particular tasks assigned to the post, and the
>   remainder handled communications, damage and diagnostics, computer
>   access, as well as a direct feed to the post's computer access. Within
>   the post was a ventilated base. The eight boards specific functions
>   included two duty monitor modules, two command interface modules, one
>   computer access module, one communications module, one secondary
>   computer access module, and one damage control module. On the duty
>   monitor module were several instruments, including a security lockdown
>   lever. The computer access module possessed several instruments,
>   including two viewscreen buttons. The communications module contained
>   several instruments, including process state indicators and a secure
>   comlink. The command interface module contained several instruments
>   including a command authority verifier. Lastly, all of the modules
>   have red blinking lights on the exterior edge of the module that acted
>   as module status indicators.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Lifting up is such an odd way to provide access. Still, a better design choice than selling a computer without an escape key. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: @1252748 - Or selling a phone without a speaker jack?

Comment: Daft Punk Posts.

Comment: @Axelrod - I assumed these were electronic drumkits, for when the Emperor wants to [drop a sick beat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXp8T097vjc&feature=youtu.be&t=2m1s).

Comment: @Valorum That was magnificent.

Answer (score -1):

Control Panels for workstations no longer in use. You would stand in the center, turn to each view screen and either monitor or activate doors/lifts/etc. There is no one there because of the impending confrontation, or maybe the controls are no longer in use, but they were at one time controlling *something*. One of those panels will slide to the side to allow someone to enter. 
Look at the star destroyers or other control panels in different ships. Nothing is exactly like this, but there are some control stations that do look like these.

Comment: Good answer, but can you provide a reference to the source you got it from?

Comment: The tower in which the Emperor had ensconced himself was not designed as a throneroom; it was originally to the be command center for the DEATH STAR, where presumably Moff Jerjerrod would be in charge.  When the emperor took over, the staff who would have been working in the tower were relocated elsewhere.  Sketches showing the original work setup for the tower were shown in the Return of the Jedi Sketchbook, with operators sitting in the workstations.